# Kotlin, как задать абстрактный массив заданного размера

Tags: массивы, kotlin

Споткнулся на пустом месте...

Надо определить абстрактное свойство типа IntArray с заданным количеством элементов

Т.е. как-то так надо

```
abstract val margins:IntArray[4]
```

или

```
abstract val margins:Array<Int>[4]
```

Чтобы в дочерних классах нельзя было переопределить массивом с отличным количеством элементов. Так вообще можно делать или я хочу странного?

**UPD**

Т.е. чтобы в наследнике было так

```
override val margins = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

А вот на такое ругалось на этапе компиляции

```
override val margins = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30)

override val margins = intArrayOf(10, 20, 30, 40, 60)
```

Comment: может нужна какая то константа?

Comment: @Vitalii не очень понял, что вы имеете в виду

Comment: что бы сама ссылка указывала на один и тот же массив а содержимое можно было менять

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самым адекватным решением (в моем случае) оказалось использование [`data class`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html) с перегруженным оператором [`get`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html)

```
data class MarginArray(val left: Int, val top: Int, val right: Int, val bottom: Int) {
    private val _values = arrayOf(left, top, right, bottom)
    operator fun get(i: Int): Int = _values[i]
}
```

Так как мне, по сути, был нужен только синтаксис доступа как к массиву, то хватило перезагрузки `get`, но никто не мешает добавить все необходимое перегрузкой операторов и проксированием методов к приватному полю `_values`, например:

```
fun toList() = _values.toList()
fun iterator() = _values.iterator()
```

Answer (score -1):

На мой взгляд, Вы хотите странного.
Зачем нужен именно абстрактный массив?

```
val margins = ArrayInt(4)
```

Comment: Потому, что у каждого дочернего класса должен быть набор из четырех Int'ов. У каждого свой уникальный. Можно, конечно, сделать 4 отдельных абстрактных поля, либо завернуть этот массив в объект, но зачем плодить лишние сущности?

Comment: Он и будет уникальным: причём не у класса, а у каждого экземпляра.

Comment: Но он будет пустой. Хочется, чтобы в дочерних можно было делать так `override val margins = arrayOf(16, 2, 4, 2)`

Comment: enum class Margin { LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, BOTTOM}
    val margins = IntArray(Margin.values().size)
    operator fun IntArray.set(m: Margin, i: Int) { this[m.ordinal] = i }
    fun initMargins(left: Int, right: Int, top: Int, bottom: Int ) {
        margins[Margin.LEFT] = left
        margins[Margin.RIGHT] = right
        margins[Margin.TOP] = top
        margins[Margin.BOTTOM] = bottom
    }

Comment: Как сделать сложно и многословно - я и сам знаю :)

Comment: fun initMargins(vararg values: Int) { for (i in margins.indices) { margins[i] = values.getOrElse(i, { 0 }) } }